# Award golden tag badges multiple times

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges

I think the golden tag badges should be awarded multiple times, e.g. every 1k upvotes.

Right now people can easily see that you are great with a certain topic if you have the golden badge but they need to look at the actual upvote count to see if you are much better in one of the topics compared to another one where you have the gold badge, too.

Comment: So someone relatively new to the site will always be at a disadvantage?

Comment: You can say that for the golden great answer/question badges, too. Most super simple but still extremely common questions have already been asked so nowadays it's **much** harder to ask a good question that becomes this popular or post an answer which receives enough attention to be upvoted that much. With tag badges however you just need to be active in that tag - of course people who already got tons of upvotes in the past will have more badges there, but it's not meant to compare with *other* people.

Comment: Or you didn't understand me correctly ;) What i meant is e.g. on http://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster?tab=badges&sort=class - you cannot know if i have e.g. 3k upvotes in python but just 1k in php or vice versa.

Comment: That _you_ don't mean for such a count to be used to compare between people doesn't mean it will not be. I suspect it will be and also end up as a comparison (I have x more gold badges in [tag:y] than Jon Skeet has).

Comment: @Lucifer: What? That's an entirely different matter altogether.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty hard to upvote your own answers :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn sorry, i found same kind of question so put that comment.

Comment: Do you really think I should have 68 gold badges for C# and 31 for Java? Personally I think that's a little over the top...

Comment: Nor everyone is a crazy as you :P

Answer (score 1):

Consider the badge and arrow point system the Boy Scouts of America uses.

The Boy Scouts have two types of badges: [Merit Badges](http://www.scouting.org/scoutsource/BoyScouts/AdvancementandAwards/MeritBadges.aspx) and [Ranks.](http://usscouts.org/advance/cubscout/ranks.asp)  Merit badges are awarded in a specific skill area; these badges are like the tag badges we award here.  Ranks are awarded based on activities completed in a wide variety of areas; these badges are similar to our Generalist, Guru and Legendary badges.

Within the ranks are a system of arrow points.  Arrow points are described as follows:

> GOLD ARROW POINT:
>
> - For the FIRST 10 arrow points completed in the "Electives" section of his book, the Wolf Cub earns his GOLD ARROW POINT.
>
> SILVER ARROW POINTS:
>
> - For EACH 10 arrow points completed (AFTER HE EARNS THE GOLD ARROW POINT) the Wolf Cub earns a SILVER ARROW POINT.
>
> He may earn any number of SILVER ARROW POINTS, but he may only earn
> ONE GOLD ARROW POINT for the first 10 elective points that he
> completes.

As you can see, a Boy Scout may earn any number of silver arrow points, and they are certainly fun to earn but the coveted gold arrow points are harder to get, and they can only be awarded once.

Comment: Sorry, is my logic broken? If I can get silver only after gold, why is it easier? Only because "electives" section is such rare/ hard? But on topic: I disagree to give tons of silver badges for same purpose you get a golden one with difference, that you get the golden one only once.